# List of regex results instead of first result in Kotlin

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

Using the following code, I can set a couple variables to my matches. I want to do the same thing, but populate a map of all instances of these results. I'm struggling and could use help.

```
val (dice, level) = Regex("""([0-9]*d[0-9]*) at ([0-9]*)""").matchEntire(text)?.destructured!!
```

This code works for one instance, none of my attempts at matching multiple are working.

Comment: I should clarify, my current code sets dice and level to the first match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is short and readable. Here are a few options the one you use is largely a matter of preference. You can get a `Map` directly by using the [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate.html) method as follows.

```
val diceLevels = levelMatches.associate { matched ->
    val (diceTwo,levelTwo) = matched.destructured
    (levelTwo to diceTwo)
}
```

Note: This creates an immutable map.  If you want a `MutableMap`, you can use [`associateTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate-to.html).

If you want to be concise, you can simplify out the destructuring to local variables and index the groups directly.

```
val diceLevels = levelMatches.associate {
    (it.groupValues[2] to it.groupValues[1])
}
```

Or, using `let`, you can also avoid needing to declare `levelMatches` as a local variable if it isn't used elsewhere --

```
val diceLevels = Regex("([0-9]+d[0-9]+) at ([0-9]+)")
        .findAll(text)
        .let { levelMatches ->
            levelMatches.associate {
                (it.groupValues[2] to it.groupValues[1])
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized this was no where near as complicated as I was making it.   Here was my solution.  Is there something more elegant?

```
val levelMatches =  Regex("([0-9]+d[0-9]+) at ([0-9]+)").findAll(text)
levelMatches.forEach { matched ->
    val (diceTwo,levelTwo) = matched.destructured
    diceLevels[levelTwo] = diceTwo
}
```